# Secondary SD Card Mount&Unmount Broadcast Receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create a broadcast receiver that receives MOUNT & UNMOUNT & EJECT of sd card. My device has 2 external directories which are **/storage/sdcard0** and second one(this is what I want to listen) **/storage/sdcard1.**
I tried some approachs those are not working. 
[android: how to listen to "sd card removed unexpectedly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973776/android-how-to-listen-to-sd-card-removed-unexpectedly)

[listener for sd-card removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552413/listener-for-sd-card-removal)
Also here is my code :

```
<!-- in manifest -->
 <receiver android:name=".system.receiver.SDCardBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL" />
            </intent-filter>

 </receiver>
//this is my java code
public class SDCardBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String MOUNTED = "android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED";
    private static final String UNMOUNTED = "android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("SDCARD",intent.getAction());//THIS NEVER TRIGGERS!!
        if(intent.getAction()!=null && intent.getAction().equals(UNMOUNTED)){

        }else if (intent.getAction()!=null && intent.getAction().equals(MOUNTED)){

        }
    }
}
```

My device is 4.4.2 version and booted device. 
I do not want to check anytime If Sd Card exists or not

Comment: Make sure that `SDCardBroadcastReceiver` class is inside package `[your package].system.receiver`.

Comment: I am sure of that. I have several broadcast in same package that are working fine

Comment: Add `<data android:scheme="file"/>` inside `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142987/media-mounted-broadcast-not-being-received