# Getting the app list from the SD Card while booting

Tags: android, package-managers, android-launcher

I made a custom launcher and using this method to retrieve list of applications in my device:

```
public class myThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... Params) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> allApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
        for(ResolveInfo ri:allApps) {
            AppInfo app = new AppInfo();
            app.label = ri.loadLabel(pm);
            app.packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
            app.activityName = ri.activityInfo.name;
            app.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(pm);
            adapter.addApp(app);
        }
        return "Success";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Collections.sort(adapter.getAppsList(),new ActivityNameComparator());
        updateStuff();
    }
```

The task is executed in the main activity `onCreate()` 
Opening this launcher when the phone is on gives no issue. I got all applications in both internal storage and SD card.
 The issue comes when I reboot my device. There is some applications that lost from the list. I then realized that those applications are those which are saved in my SD Card.
Are there any way to get apps in SD card after rebooting? Or is there a better approach to get applications list for custom launcher?

Comment: Would listening for `android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED` help? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6974252/1913542

Comment: @Nfear it helps, thanks